# Как в Atom сохранить кусок кода так, чтобы в любом файле можно было его использовать?

Tags: atom

Дело в том, что для отладки кода, приходится постоянно вводить:
console.log "..."
Хочется в какой-нибудь буфер редактора сохранить код, например:
console.log "<---!!!--->"
и с помощью горячих клавиш вставлять там, где мне это нужно.
Ctrl + c/v не предлагать.

Comment: Погугли `zen coding`.

Comment: Попробуйте поискать по фразе «как создать сниппет в atom» на YouTube. Это проще увидеть, чем объяснить.

Comment: в списке плагинов поищи **snipets**, установи и в путь (`cl` и т.п.)